# Mysql order by lower(name) case insensitive doesn't work correctly

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I want to case insensitively order by name column I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `enquiry` 
ORDER BY LOWER( name ) ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But this doesn't workas expected see the following picture where W comes before B[image]

Comment: Is there some character in front of `W` or `B`?

Comment: @C-Otto Thank you bro for your idea I added Trim and now it works